# How to check whether given binary address is ipv4 or ipv6 in c

Tags: c

i want to check whether the given address is ipv6 or ipv4. My address will come in the binary form (not in string format). In this case how can i check whether the given binary number is ipv4 or ipv6?

Comment: Sure you can.  One is 32 bits long and the other is 128 bits long.

Comment: And if you don't know the length of the address, you *can't* know the type.

Comment: ... but you can't determine how long the address actually is if you don't already know, either by the type of the object in which it is stored or by accompanying metadata.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow is not a "give me the code" site.  The question shows no effort at all to solve the problem.

Comment: Thisis not a guid question:(

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "binary form".

In general, a single, raw binary integer is not an appropriate representation for a network address.  Network addresses come in many flavors.

If you have a 32-bit number, it is *probably* an IPv4 address.  If you have a 128-bit number, it is *probably* an IPv6 address.  If you have an integer that is big enough to hold either, meaning that you have to make the determination based on value, if it is less than 4294967296, it is *probably* IPv4, else IPv6.  But none of these heuristics is guaranteed (in part because there are other kinds of network address than IPv4 and IPv6).

Virtually all APIs that deal with network addresses use a multi-field data structure to describe them concisely and unambiguously.  For example, one way of describing a network address is `struct hostent`.  Now, `struct hostent` has an `h_length` field which explicitly gives the size of the address (in bytes), so that's a start.  But then it also has an `h_addrtype` field, which explicitly tells you whether it's `AF_INET` (IPv4), `AF_INET6` (IPv6), or some other address family.  So there's no need to guess or intuit.

I would strongly encourage you to use a data structure like `struct hostent`, and not single raw binary integers, to carry network addresses around.  Using raw binary numbers is a great way to get yourself locked into IPv4, making it that much harder to expand to IPv6 now that it's time to do that.  (I speak from sad experience here. :-( )